# How can I have multiple sibling instances of the same top level fragment container?

Tags: reactjs, relay, relaymodern

I am following this guide: https://relay.dev/docs/en/quick-start-guide#composing-fragments

I am trying to create a higher level fragment container that queries data from the RootQuery:

```js
export const FormInstanceListContainer: FunctionComponent<Props> = props => {
  const { data, ...rest } = props
  const { formInstances } = data

  return (
    <FormInstanceList
      formInstances={formInstances}
      {...rest} // Forward all the other props
    />
  )
}

export default createFragmentContainer(FormInstanceListContainer, {
  data: graphql`
    fragment FormInstanceListContainer_data on RootQuery
      @argumentDefinitions(status: { type: "FormStatus" }) {
      formInstances(status: $status) {
        id
        form {
          id
          name
        }
        status
        createdAt
        submittedAt
      }
    }
  `,
})
```

This works well as long as I only need one of these lists rendered. Here is a usage example:

```js
const IndexPage: NextPage<QueryResponse> = data => {
  const handleOpenClick = (formInstance: FormInstance) => {
    NextRouter.push(`/form-instance/${formInstance.uuid}`)
  }

  const handleEditClick = (formInstance: FormInstance) => {
    NextRouter.push(`/form-instance/${formInstance.uuid}/edit`)
  }

  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <Container maxWidth="md">
        <Typography variant="h5" style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}>
          My drafts
        </Typography>

        <FormInstanceListContainer
          data={data}
          onOpenClick={handleOpenClick}
          onEditClick={handleEditClick}
        />
      </Container>
    </DefaultLayout>
  )
}

export default withData<pages_dashboard_Query>(IndexPage, {
  query: graphql`
    query pages_dashboard_Query {
      ...FormInstanceListContainer_data @arguments(status: DRAFT)
    }
  `,
})
```

Unfortunately, I need 2 of these lists rendered side by side... One for draft forms and one for submitted forms.

I can't just include expand the same fragment again:

```
    query pages_dashboard_Query {
      ...FormInstanceListContainer_data @arguments(status: DRAFT)
      ...FormInstanceListContainer_data @arguments(status: SUBMITTED)
    }
```

> ERROR:
> Expected all fields on the same parent with the name or alias 'formInstances' to have the same name and arguments.

How then can I have more than one `FormInstanceListContainer` on the same page with different data? Have I hit a dead end the way I've designed my fragment container?

---

The problem would be solved if I was able to run the queries in the top level page (since then I could use aliases) and pass the list of results to the `FormInstanceListContainer`. To do that it seems to me that the `FormInstanceListContainer` must request the fields of the query rather than the query itself:

```js
export default createFragmentContainer(FormInstanceListContainer, {
  formInstance: graphql`
    fragment FormInstanceListContainer_formInstance on FormInstance {
      id
      form {
        id
        name
      }
      status
      createdAt
      submittedAt
    }
  `,
})
```

However, now Relay assumes that a *single instance* of `FormInstance` should be passed to the container, not a list of them. Any way I try to pass a list causes Relay to crash. Is it possible to instruct Relay that it should expect a list of values rather than a single value?

I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've encountered this issue, and I think I solved it as you suggest, by including the fields that needs to aliased up in the query:

```
graphql`
   fragment FormInstanceFields on FormInstance {
      id
      form {
        id
        name
      }
      status
      createdAt
      submittedAt
   }
`
```

```
export default withData<pages_dashboard_Query>(IndexPage, {
  query: graphql`
    query pages_dashboard_Query {
      drafts: formInstances(status: DRAFT) {
        ...FormInstanceFields
      }
      submitted: formInstances(status: SUBMITTED) {
        ...FormInstanceFields
      }
    }
  `,
})
```

(Above fragment needs to be named correctly per compiler requirements)

Then the thing to do is to **not** wrap `FormInstanceList` in a fragment container, because as you point out, this leads to errors. The impulse to wrap it is strong, because using the HOC-based API, the instinct is to wrap all the way down through the render tree. But that won't work in this case.

Instead, wrap each `FormInstance` in a fragment container (which I'm guessing you're doing already already). Then it will work. The `drafts` and `submitted` fields will contain arrays of Relay store refs, and you can interate over them and pass each one to `FormInstanceContainer`.

This may feel wrong, but if you think of it from the perspective of the upcoming hooks API, or [relay-hooks](https://github.com/relay-tools/relay-hooks), there's nothing really wrong it.

---

**EDIT**

Haven't used Relay in a while, but I think you could even keep the containers at all levels by doing something like this:

```
graphql`
  fragment FormInstanceListContainer_data on RootQuery {
      drafts: formInstances(status: DRAFT) {
        ...FormInstanceFields
      }
      submitted: formInstances(status: SUBMITTED) {
        ...FormInstanceFields
      }
  }
`
```

Shouldn't that work, too?

Answer (score 0):

Relay does not allow to spread multiple fragments inside single query only if these fragments fetching data from same table with different `where clause` conditions.

All you need to do is to create single fragment instead of multiple like follwoing.

```
// Your Query...
graphql`
 query MyQuery($currentTs: bigint!) {
   ...MyFragment @arguments(currentTs:  $currentTs)
 }  


// Your Fragment...
fragment MyFragment on query_root @argumentDefinitions(
 currentTs: {type: "bigint"},     
) {
 one: appointments_connection(where: { package_type_id: { _eq: 4 }, real_status: { _in: [1, 8] }, ends_at: { _gt: $currentTs } }, first: 1, order_by: { starts_at: asc }) { 
      id 
      title
     }
 two:  appointments_connection(where: {package_type_id: {_eq: 1}}, first: 1) {
    id_random
    }
 three: appointments_connection(where: {real_status: {_in: [1, 8]}, ends_at: {_gt: $currentTs}}, first: 3, order_by: {starts_at: asc}) {
    title
    starts_at
   }
  }
```

Hope this will help to those who are new in relay.